# PHP DOM nodeValue not doesn't work

Tags: php, html, dom

I am trying to parse an HTML table with DOM and it works fine but when some cell contains html it doesn't work properly.

**Here is the Sample HTML Table**

```
<tr>
<td>Razon Social: </td>
<td>Circulo Inmobiliaria Sur (Casa Central)</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Email: </td>
<td> <img src="generateImage.php?email=myemail@domain.com"/> </td>
</tr>
```

**And PHP Code:**

```
$rows = $dom->getElementsByTagName('tr');

foreach ($rows as $row)   
{
    $cells = $row->getElementsByTagName('td');

    if(strpos($cells->item(0)->textContent, "Razon") > 0)
    {
        $_razonSocial = $cells->item(1)->textContent;
    }
    else if(strpos($cells->item(0)->textContent, "Email") > 0)
    {
        $_email = $cells->item(1)->textContent;
    }
}   

echo "Razon Social: $_razonSocial<br>Email: $_email";
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Razon Social: Circulo Inmobiliaria Sur (Casa Central) 
Email:
```

Email is empty, it must be:

```
<img src="generateImage.php?email=myemail@domain.com"/>
```

I have even tried

```
$cells->item(1)->nodeValue;
```

instead of

```
$cells->item(1)->textContent;
```

But that too doesn't work. How I can make it return HTML value?

Comment: define "doesn't work properly". Any error?

Comment: No error, it doesn't return anything. Just empty.

Comment: Is this var not empty ? $_email are u sure ?

Comment: Any idea, Shivan?
@Aveendra Its empty.

Comment: `<img src="generateImage.php?email=myemail@domain.com"/>` is not a text. It's another html-entity. `$cells->item(1)->item(0)->attr('src');` maybe

Comment: is error reporting / `display_errors` turned ON ?

Comment: @u_mulder That causes error: Call to undefined method DOMElement::item()
@ ShivanRaptor No.

Answer (score 0):

Give id to your table as item_specification

```
 $dom = new DOMDocument();
        @$dom->loadHTML($html);
        $x = new DOMXPath($dom); 


    $table = $x->query("//*[@id='item_specification']/tr");
    $rows = $table;
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
     $atr_name = $row -> getElementsByTagName('td')->item(0)->nodeValue;
     $atr_val = $row -> getElementsByTagName('td')->item(1)->nodeValue;
     }

echo " {$atr_name} - {$atr_val} <br \>";
```

Its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

As I already mentioned, `<img src="generateImage.php?email=myemail@domain.com"/>` is not a text. It's another html-entity. So try this:

```
if(strpos($cells->item(0)->textContent, "Razon") !== false) {
    $_razonSocial = $cells->item(1)->textContent;
} else if(strpos($cells->item(0)->textContent, "Email") !== false) {
    $count = 0;
    // here we get all child nodes of td.
    // space before img-tag is also a child node, but it has type DOMText
    // so we skip it.
    foreach ($cells->item(1)->childNodes as $child) {
        if (++$count == 2)
            $_email = $child->getAttribute('src');
    }
    // now in $_email you have full src value and can somehow extract email
}
```